# Reproduce JHEP.bst in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I would like to define a bibliography style with biblatex that is like the [JHEP.bst](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/JHEP.bst)
If it's not possible to reproduce it completely, it would be nice to have the closest as possible to it. The style is like the following image:
[image] which means:

- link to the journal version
- link to the ArXiv preprint version in square brackets
- All authors listed alphabetically by surname
- Full title also for books

Comment: Did you check existing BibLaTeX styles, which one(s) come close and what would need to be added?

Comment: Note that it is generally beyond the scope of this site to just ask for a complete style to be written in the answers (even though it has probably been attempted several times). Instead ask for the relevant parts of the style you want to implement separately. That way other people can benefit from your question as well and the question is easier to answer properly in one go. If you then end up with a satisfactory JHEP-like style you can always share it on GitHub or some other platform.